# Django inlineformset extra lines being ignored

Tags: django, lines, formset, extra

I am trying to add extra lines in my Form but it seems to be getting ignored. I have a similar set up as [django inlineformset_factory extra attribute being ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855567/django-inlineformset-factory-extra-attribute-being-ignored) but without the base model. I have tried to implement that solution but was not successful. Does anyone have a solution to add extra lines in my form?

Here is my code:

**Models.py**

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    disease = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="disease")

    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.disease


class Indicator(models.Model):
    relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, verbose_name="disease")       
    indicator = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="indicators")

    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.indicator
```

**Forms.py**

```
MAX_INDICATORS = 3

class DiseaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Disease

class IndicatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Indicator

DiseaseFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Disease, 
    Indicator,
    can_delete=False,
    extra=MAX_INDICATORS,
    form=DiseaseForm)

IndicatorFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Indicator,
    IndicatorValue,
    can_delete=False,
    extra=MAX_INDICATORS,
    form=IndicatorForm)
```

**Views.py**

```
def drui(request):

if request.method == "POST":

   indicatorForm  = IndicatorForm(request.POST)

   if indicatorForm.is_valid():
      new_indicator = indicatorForm.save()
      diseaseInlineFormSet = DiseaseFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new_indicator)

      if diseaseInlineFormSet.is_valid():
         diseaseInlineFormSet.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(something))

else:
   indicatorForm = IndicatorForm()
   diseaseInlineFormSet = DiseaseFormSet()

return render_to_response("something.html", {'indicatorForm': indicatorForm, 'diseaseInlineFormSet': diseaseInlineFormSet},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Updated code:** 
Now that 1 disease will be linked to multiple indicators, I can get extra lines. However, now the problem is that whenever I save my indicators and choose a disease from the database, a NEW disease will be written to the db that links to the indicators.

Views.py

```
def drui(request):
if request.method == "POST":

   diseaseForm  = DiseaseForm(request.POST)

   if diseaseForm.is_valid():
      new_disease = diseaseForm.save(commit=False)
      indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(request.POST, instance=new_disease)

      if indicatorInlineFormSet.is_valid():
         new_disease.save()
         indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(valdrui))

else:
   diseaseForm = DiseaseForm()
   indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(instance=Disease())

return render_to_response("drui.html", {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm, 'indicatorInlineFormSet': indicatorInlineFormSet},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class DiseaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    disease = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Disease.objects.all())
    class Meta:
       model = Disease

class IndicatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Indicator  

IndicatorFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Disease, 
    Indicator,
    can_delete=False,
    extra=MAX_INDICATORS)
```

HTML:

```
{{ diseaseForm.as_table }}
{{ indicatorInlineFormSet.as_table }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you have a single `IndicatorForm` for a single `Indicator` instance, along with a `DiseaseFormSet` to bind multiple `Disease` instances to that single `Indicator`. Yet in your models.py you have a `ForeignKey` from `Indicator` to `Disease`, meaning that an `Indicator` can only be bound to one single `Disease` instance, while a `Disease` instance can have as many `Indicators` as you want.

To fix it, change the `ForeignKey` from being in the `Indicator` model to the `Disease` model, to being in the `Disease` model to the `Indicator` model - or if you want it the other way around, stick with the models you've got and use an `IndicatorFormSet` with a single `DiseaseForm`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I went with the latter and stuck with the models so that 1 disease can have multiple indicators. However, a new problem arose such that a new Disease is created in my database table every time I submit. I would like to be able to pick from choses in the database and have indicators linked to the disease I chose. My previous solution was able to do that.

Comment: Hm it seems to me you actually want multiple diseases for a single indicator and multiple indicators for a single disease? Use a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield). Anyway, can you update the code in your question?

Comment: I actually want just multiple indicators for a single disease (hopefully this makes things easier). I'll update the code in my question.